# How to share a Google Maps Engine Lite Map without forcing the users to login to Google

Tags: google-maps

I am not able  to find documentation about the current status of this feature.

I am trying to share a link to a map with a group of friends. The map has been created with "Google Maps Engine Lite". Some of my friends have google accounts, and some not. I do not want to force anybody to log-in to google in order to see my map. I have set the map to "Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view", and I get a link to share:

```
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=xxxxx.yyyyyy
```

But that is an "edit" link, which forces the users to login. I have tried to replace "edit" by "viewer", as I found in a forum:

```
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/viewer?mid=xxxxx.yyyyyy
```

But no luck: google just redirects to edit, and requires a login.

So, here my questions:

1. Is it possible to view a map without login in?
2. If yes, how?
3. If not, why is Google advertising a "Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view", when that is not true? This is very confusing! (log-in does not count as "public on the web" in my book)

Answer (score 2):

I just made a new test map, and got a link of https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zP0WdvBIEvn4.kdgYmd2BVd2g which, when viewed from an incognito (not logged in) window redirects to a /viewer link for me, and does not require a login.

Does this map work for you?

If you are still having issues, can you confirm you hit 'Done' after setting your map to public in the sharing dialog?

Comment: Your map is indeed working, but mine is not. I'll try to find out where the difference lies (I did indeed click "Done")

Comment: If you get stuck, and are willing to share the URL, that may help troubleshoot

Comment: Sure, thanks: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zSB7ddxbKjrs.kiwrT62glwNQ

Comment: I am able to view that with no issues in a fresh (not logged in) browser.  It redirects me to https://mapsengine.google.com/map/viewer?mid=zSB7ddxbKjrs.kiwrT62glwNQ -- are you still experiencing something different?  If so, which browser/OS combo?  What's the default language?

Comment: I have now tried with a clean chrome (with an empty user-data-dir: `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/empty`) and now it works. So it seems that, whenever google detects an active session **or** a logged-out session, it forces the user to login. It is not possible to *just* view the map whenever a session is detected in the cache - and it does not matter whether the session is active or inactive.

Comment: And the bad thing about this is: let's say you have no google login. But a friend of yours has logged in to google in your browser (he was visiting). Your friend left one week ago, and he logged out before closing the browser (good for him!), so no google session is active. Now you try to open the map in view mode. Google detects that a session is in the cache, an offers you to login. You do not know the password for your friend, so you can not log in. The only option left is to manually clean the cache - which most users are not able to do. Google should let you go proceed without logging in!

Comment: I am unable to replicate:  1) login 2) create map 3) share map publicly 4) logout 5) I am able to view the map with no trouble.  Can you start from scratch and outline how to replicate?

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace the /map/edit or /map/viewer by /map/embed

```
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=xxxxx.yyyyyy
```